# Unable to start neo4j server 2.1.2

Tags: java, macos, neo4j

I'm unable to start the latest Neo4j community server 2.1.2 on OSX with java 7.
After downloading and extracting the neo4j-community-2.1.2-unix.tar.gz I've tried to run ./bin/neo4j start without modifying any configuration or data dir, but it fails with

```
neo4j-community-2.1.2 markus$ ./bin/neo4j start 
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC - org.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user 
process [14899]... waiting for server to be ready................................. Failed to start within 120 seconds. 
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

The data/log/console.log does not contain much useful:

```
2014-06-20 06:24:04.865+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
```

I am running java 7 on OSX Mavericks 10.9.2:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas of what is going wrong or how to better debug the problem appreciated

Comment: What is in data/graph.db/messages.log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same problem.

In my case it was because `neo4j-shell` tried to use the used port `1337`.

Just edit the last line in `conf/neo4j.properties` and change the port to something else, like

```
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337
remote_shell_port=1338
```

Comment: Excellent, that was it! I should have checked used port, but would be nice if neo would let us know about used ports. Thanks!

Comment: Tks! Worked for me too. +1

Comment: Didn't work to me. BTW, why 1337 is only available to `root`? I know that ports below 1024 are root privileged.