# Error on neo4j server start on arch linux

Tags: linux, neo4j, archlinux, su

I have an arch linux setup and installed neo4j through the arch user repository (`yaourt -S neo4j`), and I'm able to run the web console fine (`sudo neo4j console` with seemingly normal output and full functionality), however when trying to start the server (`sudo neo4j start`), I encounter the following error message:

```
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/utils: line 345: [: -lt: unary operator expected
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/etc/neo4j/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/neo4j/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...cat: /run/neo4j/neo4j-service.pid: No such file or directory
process []... waiting for server to be ready. Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
rm: cannot remove ‘/run/neo4j/neo4j-service.pid’: No such file or directory
```

There's no delay before the error message is printed, so it seems to be something other than the timeout. I'm quite new to neo4j (I worked through a fair bit of the user manual using the web console, but no development or server config experience), so I'm not really sure what else might be relevant. I tried looking through the utils script and the error appears to be where it attempts to `su neo4j`, but it also seems to proceed to attempt to start the server. I also tried changing the port it's starting on as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321306/unable-to-start-neo4j-server-2-1-2), but no change. The only log I can find just has this over and over (with appropriate timestamps):

```
Oct 15, 2014 1:33:49 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
```

Any help at all would be appreciated!

EDIT:
The line 345 that it's failing on is the end of this snippet:

```
if [ $UID == 0 ] ; then
  OPEN_FILES=`su $NEO4J_USER -c "ulimit -n"`
else
  OPEN_FILES=`ulimit -n`
fi    
if [ $OPEN_FILES -lt 40000 ]; then
```

From doing some echo debugging, it seems that `su $NEO4J_USER` is failing, probably because $NEO4J_USER is set to neo4j, a user that does not exist on my system. I tried setting that to root in one of the config files, but evidently that's not working properly. Arch is a continual learning experience for me, but I've not had to add a new user before to get software working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interesting line here is:

```
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/utils: line 345: [: -lt: unary operator expected
```

I assume that is caused by a wrong default shell for the neo4j user. What default is currently set for the `neo4j` system user? Try to switch that to bash. The startup scripts should work nicely with bash.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I added some context to that line in my question. I don't think it's a bash issue, but it could definitely have to do with misconfiguring of the neo4j user (since he doesn't exist). I had tried setting the default user to be root, but that doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm away from the relevant machine right now, but I can try some things tonight if you have any suggestions!

Comment: Got a chance to have a look at that! Looks like the user is created by yaourt, and the shell was set to /bin/false! good call, Stefan! Accepting as the answer, since I now have a neo4j server! Thanks!

Comment: Don't know much regarding Arch Linux. However on Debian/Ubuntu when installing neo4j via package manager (apt-get) a neo4j user is created. I guess the same should happen for arch as well.

Comment: addendum: please note that the arch linux packages for neo4j are not maintained by neo4j team itself so you might want to  reach out to the package maintainer, see https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/neo4j/